# Daddy's skin is very tickly

Tags: meaning, word-in-context

> Skin is lumpy,  skin is prickly. Daddy's skin is very ***tickly***!

[image]

What does tickly mean here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tickly, in this context, means that is is tickling the children!  It is presumably referring to the fact that daddy has hair all over his body, and these hairs tickle the children.